# How to sort this array/map in Dart?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, dart

How to sort this map/array from "data" in Dart?

```
var training = [
  {"data" : "15/10/2019" , "pic" : "assets/images/foto3.jpg"},
  {"data" : "10/10/2019" , "pic" : "assets/images/foto5.jpg"},
  {"data" : "15/10/2019" , "pic" : "assets/images/foto4.jpg"},
  {"data" : "30/10/2019" , "pic" : "assets/images/bocateam.jpg"},
  {"data" : "17/10/2019" , "pic" : "assets/images/foto2.jpg"},
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to sort after but I am going to guess it is by date from the "data" value. Please take a look at this implementation and tell me if there are anything you don't understand:

```
void main() {
  final training = [
    {"data": "15/10/2019", "pic": "assets/images/foto3.jpg"},
    {"data": "10/10/2019", "pic": "assets/images/foto5.jpg"},
    {"data": "15/10/2019", "pic": "assets/images/foto4.jpg"},
    {"data": "30/10/2019", "pic": "assets/images/bocateam.jpg"},
    {"data": "17/10/2019", "pic": "assets/images/foto2.jpg"},
  ];

  training.sort((map1, map2) {
    final date1 = parseDate(map1['data']);
    final date2 = parseDate(map2['data']);
    return date1.compareTo(date2);
  });

  training.forEach(print);
  //  {data: 10/10/2019, pic: assets/images/foto5.jpg}
  //  {data: 15/10/2019, pic: assets/images/foto3.jpg}
  //  {data: 15/10/2019, pic: assets/images/foto4.jpg}
  //  {data: 17/10/2019, pic: assets/images/foto2.jpg}
  //  {data: 30/10/2019, pic: assets/images/bocateam.jpg}
}

// Format: 15/10/2019
DateTime parseDate(String date) {
  final parts = date.split('/');
  return DateTime(
      int.parse(parts[2]), int.parse(parts[1]), int.parse(parts[0]));
}
```

The implementation could be more efficient if each date are first converted to `DateTime` objects so we don't need to convert each object multiple times when we sort. But if the list are rather short it is not a major problem.

Comment: Thanks. Very clean.